# Unit testing and error 500

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm an absolute newbie to Unit Testing, but I feel the need to learn something about it while I'm making my switch to CakePHP 3.

Following the manual, I've installed phpunit through composer (the same as I did for the whole cake package), created an empty test database and given config/app.php the right informations on how to connect.

Through the bake plugin I've baked some tests (I've got 19 tests now). Each one of them is (correctly) marked as incomplete.

Now, I'm trying to write a test for one of my controller's index function, this is what I've done:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->Session([
        'Auth' => [
            'User' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'email' => 'test@test.com',
                'level' => 'adm',
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $this->get('/invoices');
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

The problem is that it just doesn't work, and I don't know what is throwing that 500 error...

```
Status code is not between 200 and 204
Failed asserting that 500 is equal to 204 or is less than 204.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try inspecting what the response body is?

Comment: The only thing I have tried is putting this echo $this->_response->body(); instead of assertResponse, but reading that debug in the console is not so easy and I didn't find anything interesting

Comment: I've saved the output to an html file and I have found the problem. Looks lke there was something wrong with fixtures. Thank you for your suggestion!